# Combing/Collapsing binary variables into a single row by patient ID in SAS

Tags: sas

I am trying to collapse my multiple rows of binary variables into a single row per patient id as depicted in my illustration. Could someone please help me with the SAS code to do this? Thanks[image: Illustration of data have and want]

Comment: What is the rule for collapsing?

Comment: By patient ID, so if you can see in the picture, I only want one row per patient ID, so the variables 2018, 2019, and 2020 are the reason there are multiple rows per person now, but I just need to get them in a single row where that we can see in 1 line per person if the id was present in 2018, 2019, and 2020

Comment: Do not post data as images, please post as text. Images means we would need to type out your data to test any solutions.

Comment: So do you want 1 only if ALL of the values are one?  Or do you want 1 if ANY of the values are one?

Comment: Why are your column headers numbers instead of variable names?

Comment: 1 if any of the values are one. The headers are years. We are trying to see what years an id shows up, but trying to collapse into a single row. If an id appears in multiple years, there will be more than 1 row, but we are just trying to get that into one. This post (https://communities.sas.com/t5/SAS-Programming/Combine-Collapse-Binary-Variables-By/td-p/102456) asked a very similar question if it is more clear here, I just couldn't get the code to work

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the rule is that to set it to 1 if it is ever 1 then take the MAX.  If the rule is to set it to one only if all of them are one then take the MIN.

```
proc summary data=have nway ;
  by id;
  output out=want max= ;
run;
```

Comment: Great, I think that worked this time. Thank you so much.

Comment: You will need a VAR statement or MAX(list of vars)=;  PROC MEANS would default to all numeric VARS not mentioned in other statements.

Comment: Any chance you know how to do this in R?

Answer (score 2):

Update trick

```
data want;
update have(obs=0) have;
by id;
run;
```

Or

```
proc sql;
create table want as
select ID, max('2018'n) as Y2018, max('2019'n) as Y2019, max('2020'n) as Y2020
from have
group by ID
order by ID;
quit;
```

Untested because you provided data as images, please post as text, preferably as a data step.

Comment: Update won't work for this if zeros were missing it could work.  I would use PROC SUMMARY over SQL much less typing.

Comment: Yeah, actually, I think I spoke too soon. That only kept one line, whereas I want all lines per patient id collapsed into 1 row. I made that data up that's why its just a picture

Comment: Agree with proc summary except for variable names like this you'd still have to list them manually so the gain is small. Depends on actual data structure.

Comment: @Sophia Even copying and pasting the raw Excel data is better than pictures, there are SO guidelines on this, not just my personal preference.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a data step-based solution. Certainly more complex than the above answers, but it does show ways you can use arrays, `first.` and `last.` processing, and the `retain` statement.

Use a retained temporary array to hold the values of `2018`-`2020` until the last observation of each `id` group. On the last value of each `id`, check if each held value is 1 and set each value of the year to a 1 or 0.

```
data want;
    set have;
    by id;

    array year[3] '2018'n--'2020'n;
    array hold[3] _TEMPORARY_;
    retain hold;

    if(first.id) then call missing(of hold[*]);

    do i = 1 to dim(year);
        if(year[i] = 1) then hold[i] = 1;
    end;

    if(last.id) then do;
        do i = 1 to dim(year);
            year[i] = (hold[i] = 1);
        end;

        output;
    end;

    drop i;

run;
```